# Why are Lightning Actions for Case Object showing in Feed?

Tags: lightning, button, action, page-layout, casefeed

I'm trying to create a button for a case detail page.
However I can't get anything to show in the highlights panel at the top.
I've created a new page layout for Case that isn't feed tracked but it still shows in the feed.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 5):

This is a expected behaviour from salesforce when feed tracking is enabled for cases or work orders, the page-level action menu on those records contains only custom buttons and supported standard buttons. Quick actions appear on the Chatter tab.

So in order to not see the action in feed, you need to disable the feed tracking for your case object.

Steps are:- setup--> feed tracking--> select case--> disable it and save

[image]

Reference:- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_in_lex.htm&type=0

### Update

In winter 21, You can actually do this using Lightning App Builder dynamic actions. Upgrade your page to dynamic actions and add the quick actions using lightning app builder. It will come in highlight panel even if feed tracking is enabled.

Check out this blog:- [ADD QUICK ACTION IN HIGHLIGHT PANEL ON CASE OBJECT LIGHTNING RECORD PAGE EVEN IF FEED TRACKING IS ENABLED](https://salesforcediaries.com/2020/12/28/add-quick-action-in-highlight-panel-on-case-object-lightning-record-page-even-if-feed-tracking-is-enabled/)

[image]

Comment: How do i get Custom Buttons to show on the page-level action menu?

Comment: In order to show, you need to disable feed tracking following these steps:-setup--> feed tracking--> select case--> disable it and save